# How do I remove goswagger?

Tags: apt

I wanted to install `goswagger` on Ubuntu 20.04 (according to [this page](https://goswagger.io/install.html)). It failed saying that with the message

```
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/go-swagger/goswagger-debian ubuntu Release' does not have a Release file.
```

And now every time I run `sudo apt update` I get this error. How can I clean it?

Comment: Remove this repository in Software & Updates.

Comment: I use WSL - no UI. I need some CLI solution

Comment: So remove it from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added an entry to the sources list. You need to remove it, the following command will open the sources list so you can edit it. Remove the entry in this case the one for bintray.

You need to remove the PPA that you added from the sources list.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After this is done that entry will be removed and it will not look for it when you you run an update.

This command is run from the terminal.